# How to get MS Edge to automatically sign into a web site?

Tags: windows-10, security, automation, microsoft-edge

I have multiple security cameras set up that record to an NVR appliance, which has a web server built into it for viewing camera footage.  I'm trying to set up a wall-mounted TV so that people can monitor the cameras live, and I've attached a small form-factor PC running Win10 to it.

The goal is to have this PC be "zero touch", as there is no mouse and keyboard attached to it.  The idea is that the PC automatically logs into Windows with a low-rights account and runs the built-in Edge client in kiosk mode straight to the URL that has all the cameras laid out on the screen properly.  If the computer ever reboots (after Windows updates or a power outage for example), I don't want to have to fiddle with it to get the footage back.  It needs to "just work".

The problem is that I can't get Edge to automatically log into the web page.  I set it to remember the username/password, and that works.  But you have to start typing the username before it will auto-fill the form and hit the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key to sign in.  I've done this successfully with Internet Explorer in the past (using integrated Windows authentication), but this NVR page doesn't work correctly in IE.

Is there a way to get MS Edge to automatically authenticate the way IE did?  I would prefer to avoid using Chrome/Firefox/3rd-party plugins if I can get away with it, since those things would need to be updated regularly and (ideally) this machine will not have Internet access.

Also FYI, this is the Chromium-based Edge we're talking about, not "Legacy" edge.

Comment: Hi Wes - Does the NVR have api access where the username and other fields can be passed in the url as parameters at execution time? If so, you could see what levels of authentication the NVR application server supports and integrate accordingly into the URL you use for the kiosk site to open.

Comment: @ITThugNinja; Not sure but quite possibly. It's a kinda expensive one so I'll have to look into that.

Comment: If you can tell me the make and model of the appliance, I can look into it from the Internet too as there might be some manuals I can look over that's out here somewhere.

Comment: @ITThugNinja; It's a Milestone XProtect NVR. I didn't buy it, haven't seen it, don't know much about it. But I found out that they have a software client that supports integrated Windows auth, so I think I'll explore that. But If you find a way to do it via a simple web page, that'd be my preferred route. I want this PC to be as "thin" as possible.